# Difficulties Using Web Fonts In HTML Email Template

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-email, webfonts

I'm designing some HTML email templates for work and am having varying results while attempting to incorporate web-fonts.

I've been using Outlook, Gmail and Yahoo Mail to test my templates. Outlook and Gmail seem to be displaying the fonts on web but not on mobile. Yahoo seems to ignore the fonts on both. All three seem to ignore when I use the font-weight property as well.

For reference I'm trying to use Josefin Sans and Lato Google fonts.

Here's what I'm using to get the fonts:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&family=Lato:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this is an example of me trying to use the font and the desired font weight:

```html
<td style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;">
      Testing Lato Font
</td>
```

I would like to know if it's something I'm doing wrong or a limitation on the CSS imposed by the email client? If its the latter are there any work arounds to consider?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/, web fonts will only work on Apple Mail, Outlook on Mac, Outlook on some versions of iOS, Samsung app and a couple of others. Outlook app & Outlook.com may have had an update at some point to add support also.

I would grab that href there, go to it in the browser, and copy just the @font-face Latin parts. There's better support for @font-face than a link, and, you'll need to adjust for Outlook on Windows. (Or, look at this way, the link or the @import method also require the @font-face, so there's no point in complicating things by adding them too.)

So here's what you'll end up with:

```
<style>
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v17/S6u9w4BMUTPHh7USSwiPGQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
mso-font-alt: Arial;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v17/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wXg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
mso-font-alt: Arial;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v17/S6u9w4BMUTPHh6UVSwiPGQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
mso-font-alt: Arial;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v17/S6u9w4BMUTPHh50XSwiPGQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
mso-font-alt: Arial;
}
</style>
```

Notice `mso-font-alt: Arial;` in each declaration - that's so Outlook for Windows doesn't default to Times New Roman (it doesn't support web fonts).

Now, Google only support Google Sans and Roboto font, so you might want to do this in your font-family: `font-family: 'Lato', Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300;`

Always make sure you have a websafe font in that list (e.g. Arial). This is a font that almost everyone has installed already. And the sans-serif is for those 0.1% that don't even have that, but you don't want it defaulting to serif like Times New Roman.